# Order 2 elements in finite characteristic field

Tags: field-theory

In  field of characteristic $p$, where $p$ is prime, why can $x^2=1$ only have the two solutions $1$ and $-1$? Is it just because that polynomial only has degree 2?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: In *any* field the polynomial $x^2-1$ has only the roots $1$ and $-1$; if the characteristic is $2$, then the roots are coincident, otherwise they're distinct.

Comment: $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ If you substitute a value not equal to $1$ or $-1$ then the two factors are nonzero. In any ring without zerodivisors the outcome will be nonzero as well.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial $X^2-1$ has at most two solutions due to $\Bbb K$ and thus $\Bbb K[X]$ being an integral domain.

Note that in a ring with zero divisors a polynomial of degree $n$ can have more that $n$ roots. For example in $\Bbb Z_8$ the roots of $X^2-1$ are $1,3,5,$ and $7$.